# Verifying fcm token issued for domain

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, devicetoken

I use *https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/id_token* api
this api works fine for chrome browser generated tokens and shows domain(eg. shopify.com) of generated token, but for firefox browser tokens it doesn't show domain of generated token.

Is it possible to get domain name for all browser based tokens from fcm device token?

I also tried FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(idToken); but it seems I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

This result is returned from https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/id_token for chrome browser generated token which is fine

```
{
   "application": "com.chrome.linux",
   "subtype": "wp:https://xxxxx.com/#10BBB956-A63F-4D91-B8C8-474A85325-V2",
   "scope": "*",
   "authorizedEntity": "107xxxxxxxx4",
   "platform": "BROWSER"
 }
```

I need to get the same result for firefox browser token

Answer (score 0):

However I have not found my answer yet but I have found two ways to restrict domain names to use my api key from this link [google cloud collective confirmed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484053/11393852)